# Spring JMS listener-container concurrency attribute not working

Tags: java, concurrency, spring-jms

Hi I am learning Spring JMS with ActiveMQ. 
In my example scenario is Producer application sends around 50 messages in queue and when I start Consumer application it starts to  consume those messages.

Now I want multiple consumer threads to consume messages from queue.
I am using **JMS listener-container**. When I googled for that I found there is a **concurrency** attribute.

According to [Spring JMS doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace) concurrency attribute specifies

> The number of concurrent sessions/consumers to start for each listener. Can either be a simple number indicating the maximum number (e.g. "5") or a range indicating the lower as well as the upper limit (e.g. "3-5"). Note that a specified minimum is just a hint and might be ignored at runtime. Default is 1; keep concurrency limited to 1 in case of a topic listener or if queue ordering is important; consider raising it for general queues.

But in my configuration I am setting this attribute to 5 but it seems it fails to start 5 concurrent listeners.

Configuration for listener:

**consumer-applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"

    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />

    <bean id="listener" class="com.jms.example.MyMessageListener"></bean>

    <jms:listener-container container-type="default" concurrency="5"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory">
        <jms:listener destination="MyQueue" ref="listener"
            method="onMessage"></jms:listener>
    </jms:listener-container>

</beans>
```

And If I used bean **DefaultMessageListenerContainer** instead of **jms:listener-container** with properties:

```
<bean id="msgListenerContainer" 
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
        p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"
        p:destination-ref="destination"
        p:messageListener-ref="listener"
        p:concurrentConsumers="10"
        p:maxConcurrentConsumers="50" />
```

Then in ActiveMQ console I could see 10 consumers but in reality it starts 3 consumers simultaneously or sometimes 6 or only 1 consumer.

**EDIT:**

Consumer code:

```
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener{


    public void onMessage(Message m) {
        TextMessage message=(TextMessage)m;
        try{
            System.out.println("Start = " + message.getText());
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("End = " + message.getText());
        }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();  }
    }
}
```

I am printing consumed messages on console whose output is explained in scenarios below:

**OBSERVATION:**

I observed some weird behavior. 
My producer and consumer are two independent applications.

**Scenario - 1:**

1. I start producer and send messages(Meanwhile consumer is NOT running)
2. Then I start consumer to consume messages.

Here problem is it does not loads all 10 consumers. Sometimes it loads 3 OR 1.

```
Start = hello jms 1 // consumer 1 started 
Start = hello jms 2 // consumer 2 started 
Start = hello jms 3 // consumer 3 started 
End = hello jms 1  //  consumer 1 ended
Start = hello jms 4 // consumer 4 started and hence always 3 consumers and not 10
End = hello jms 2
Start = hello jms 5
End = hello jms 3
Start = hello jms 6
```

**Scenario - 2:**

1. I start producer and send messages(Meanwhile consumer is running)
2. Since the consumer is in running state it starts to consume them.

So it does load all 5 consumers properly as expected. so the output is:

```
Start = hello jms 1 // consumer 1 started 
Start = hello jms 2 // consumer 2 started 
Start = hello jms 3 // consumer 3 started 
Start = hello jms 4 // consumer 4 started 
Start = hello jms 5 // consumer 5 started 
Start = hello jms 6 // consumer 6 started 
Start = hello jms 7 // consumer 7 started 
Start = hello jms 8 // consumer 8 started 
Start = hello jms 9 // consumer 9 started 
Start = hello jms 10 // consumer 10 started. Hence all them started at same time as expected.
End = hello jms 1
Start = hello jms 11
End = hello jms 2
Start = hello jms 12
End = hello jms 3
Start = hello jms 13
```

Why is this happening. It is really eating my brain.
I don't want to keep consumer to be running forever. I want to keep both detached.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "in reality it starts 3 consumers simultaneously" ? If you can see 10 consumers in AMQ console, then you have 10 consumers. Try give it steady load over time and you will notice all 10 consumers will get load.

Comment: @PetterNordlander I will just update my question to bring in clarity.

Comment: @PetterNordlander please see my edit. I mean to say in my consumer code i am printing received message text. So from output it looks like it has started 3 consumers simultaneously and not 10.

Comment: @PetterNordlander please see my observations in the question above. I have updated my question.

Comment: @mahendra if you specify only one number it means a "maximum" number of consumers will be started. Which mean always less than "maximum" is started unless Spring JMS thinks it needs more. Try to specify a range with a minimum value and give your consumer a steady load (not 50 messages). And you will see all consumers working up to the specified maximum.

Comment: @Strelok By the term steady load you mean I should increase number of messages and specify range for consumers. Right ?

Comment: Just start your consumer program and then start your producer to produce messages in an infinite loop as fast as possible. You will see all your consumers working.

Comment: Yes that way I can see. But consumer and producer are 2 independent applications. Consumer may not be available at the same time when producer sends messages.

Comment: And If I first start producer and send messages and then start consumer I can see it is hardly consuming with 3 threads maximum and not 5

Comment: Well.. DMLC is built to adjust to a given load with some algorithm.  I fail to see the problem. As well, DMLC is not really built to scale well with start/stop behavior. Rather it's usually kept running with a given amount of max consumers. If you want to do some detailed tweaks on this, consider implementing your own message listener and threading, or extend DMLC

Comment: Your consumers can be prefetching many messages at ones from the queue. The answers in this question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583161/defaultmessagelistenercontainer-not-scaling

Comment: @Strelok But I am not setting any `prefetch` attribute on listener-container

Comment: @Gary Russell can you provide some suggestion on this ? I have posted my solution below. But just want to know is this proper way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

Just met this problem on spring-boot 1.5.9 application.

As pointed out by @Strelok and @mahendra kawde, the issue is due to prefetchPolicy parameter. The default value is 1000.

> Large prefetch values are recommended for high performance with high message volumes. However, for lower message volumes, where each message takes a long time to process, the prefetch should be set to 1. This ensures that a consumer is only processing one message at a time. Specifying a prefetch limit of zero, however, will cause the consumer to poll for messages, one at a time, instead of the message being pushed to the consumer.

Take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

One can change prefetchPolicy parameter as following:

1. In `application.properties` file ([working example](https://github.com/estarter/jms-spring-camel-demo/tree/conf1))

   ```
   spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1
   ```
2. In DefaultMessageListenerContainer by modifying destinationName parameter ([working example](https://github.com/estarter/jms-spring-camel-demo/tree/conf2))

   ```
   <bean id="cons-even" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
     <property name="destinationName" value="queue-name?consumer.prefetchSize=1"/>
     ...
   </bean>
   ```
3. In ConnectionFactory bean ([working example](https://github.com/estarter/jms-spring-camel-demo/tree/conf3)):

   ```
   @Bean
   public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
       ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
       ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy policy = new ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy();
       policy.setQueuePrefetch(1);
       factory.setPrefetchPolicy(policy);
       return factory;
   }
   ```

Related topics:

1. [How do I make Spring JMSListener burst to max concurrent threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492496/how-do-i-make-spring-jmslistener-burst-to-max-concurrent-threads)
2. [Dynamic scaling of JMS consumer in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042909/dynamic-scaling-of-jms-consumer-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

As Strelok pointed me about prefetching of messages. Created `prefetchPolicy` bean with `queuePrefetch` property set to 1.
Whose reference is set in connectionFactory.

I did some changes in configuration, those are as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"

    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"
        p:prefetchPolicy-ref="prefetchPolicy" />

    <bean id="prefetchPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy"
        p:queuePrefetch="1" />

    <bean id="listener" class="com.javatpoint.MyMessageListener"></bean>

    <jms:listener-container concurrency="10-15" connection-factory="connectionFactory">
        <jms:listener destination="javatpointQueue" ref="listener"
            method="onMessage"></jms:listener>
    </jms:listener-container>

    <!-- The JMS destination -->

      <bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="javatpointQueue" />
      </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: @Gary Russell Can you tell me when to use spring jmsTemplate and when to use Spring Integration JMS ? If I want to replace my existing config with Spring Integraion JMS then what all I need to care of ?

Answer (score 0):

JMS can work in concurrency mode. Below I am sharing the sample snippet 
***concurrentConsumers = 100 value***

[Spring JMS Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-jms)

```
<bean id="listenerContainer"        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="concurrentConsumers">
            <value>100</value>
        </property>
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="queue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false" />
        <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value="1" />
    </bean>
```