# Dynamic scaling of JMS consumer in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, activemq-classic

I am trying to build a spring-boot application which will read data from a activeMQ producer. I want to resources available on customer to the optimum.In my spring-boot application, I want to configure multiple consumers and all these consumer will connect to a single queue.

Is their a way I can dynamically scale up and scale down the consumers on sprint-boot application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the consumers your are talking about, are different thread of the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` or different instances of `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` ?

you can increase and decrease dynamically threads number of DefaultMessageListenerContainer by changing

```
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.concurrentConsumers
```

and

`org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.maxConcurrentConsumers`
accordingly

**UPDATE**

if you work with multiple consumers and/or threads you need to adapt the prefetchPolicy.

```
persistent queues (default value: 1000)
non-persistent queues (default value: 1000)
persistent topics (default value: 100)
non-persistent topics (default value: Short.MAX_VALUE - 1)
```

all messages was dispatched to the first connected consumer and when another one connects he don't receive messages,  so to change this behavior if you have concurrent consumer for a queue you need to set prefetchPolicy to a lower value than default. for example add this `jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1` to the uri config in activemq.xml or set it on the client url like this

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://172.16.143.99:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1");
```

> Large prefetch values are recommended for high performance with high
>   message volumes. However, for lower message volumes, where each
>   message takes a long time to process, the prefetch should be set to 1.
>   This ensures that a consumer is only processing one message at a time.
>   Specifying a prefetch limit of zero, however, will cause the consumer
>   to poll for messages, one at a time, instead of the message being
>   pushed to the consumer.

Take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

And

http://activemq.apache.org/destination-options.html

Comment: I have multiple instance of the same application and I planning to create multiple consumer in each instance.Is it a optimal solution?

Comment: multiple threads in the same instance of DMLC ok but why multiple  instances of DMLC (consumer) and applications to consume from a single queue ?

Comment: To maintain fail-safe for these instances. If the instance configured with DMLC goes down than the message processing will stop.

Comment: ok if differents DMLC instances are running in different clusters or servers

Comment: Yes, I have 3 instances in different machine and trying to synchronize a external resource.

Comment: i have updated my answer to prevent the case that the consumers connecting after the first one do not receive messages

Comment: Can this configuration be applied in run time?

Comment: after the ActiveMQConnection creation or before ? if before through the ActiveMQConnectionFactory or if after org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.setPrefetchPolicy(ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy)

Comment: the consumers created with a prefetchPolicy cannot be changed later